# Strip character in a php 'for' loop/mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, character, strip

I have a loop that successfully shows account numbers. Some of these numbers were saved into the db with an "@" prepended. I would like to strip the "@" sign from the displayed results. I've seen plenty of solutions for a simple echo that accomplishes this by using `trim`, `preg_replace`, etc, but nothing within a `for` loop. Any ideas?

My current code (not including an attempted solution):

```
<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT banner_id FROM tablename") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($query, $dblink) or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
if($result){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $banner_id[$i] = $row['banner_id'];
    $i++;
  }
}
?>
<html><body>
<ul>
<?php     
    for($x=0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++) {
        echo "<li>{$banner_id[$x]}</li>\n";
    }
?>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Current Output:

- 12345678
- @98765432
- @01230145

Desired Output:

- 12345678
- 98765432
- 01230145

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't find anything that works. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: There's nothing magical about the variables within a loop structure. Not sure what your problem is, as you don't say what you tried that doesn't work. You just indicate that whatever you tried doesn't work. SHOW WHAT DIDN'T WORK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't get why you think you can't use `trim()` inside a `for` loop.

```
<?php     
    for($x=0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++) {
        $out = ltrim($banner_id[$x], '@');
        echo "<li>$out</li>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: since it's only needing to remove from the beginning surely using `ltrim` would be more efficient?

Comment: Thanks, lorenzo-s. I tried something similar, but I was just off the mark. Your solution (and -- yes, Nick -- using `ltrim`) worked perfectly. You guys rock.

Answer (score 3):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $banner_id[$i] = trim( $row['banner_id'], '@' );
    $i++;
}
```

Anything you've found that you can do during print can also occur before printing. I'd avoid preg_* functions on a simple replace like this though.

---

**Edit:** After seeing the other comments, I realized that `str_replace` was much slower than `trim`, and `trim` is marginally faster than `ltrim`.

My test code:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $test = '@123345567';
    $test = str_replace('@', '', $test);
}

$time = microtime(true) - $start;
print "str_replace(): $time";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $test = '@123345567';
    $test = trim($test, '@');
}

$time = microtime(true) - $start;
print "<br/>trim(): $time";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $test = '@123345567';
    $test = ltrim($test, '@');
}

$time = microtime(true) - $start;
print "<br />ltrim(): $time";
```

A few results:

```
str_replace(): 0.64844393730164
trim(): 0.50381588935852
ltrim(): 0.51557087898254

str_replace(): 0.65361404418945
trim(): 0.49786400794983
ltrim(): 0.51703000068665

str_replace(): 0.64999985694885
trim(): 0.49114680290222
ltrim(): 0.5248019695282
```

Comment: +1.5 for the test, -0.5 for making me mad about why `ltrim` is slower than `trim` :D Seriously, why?!

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/string.c#php_trim Looks to be that trim uses native functions, r and l trim use more processing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `echo "<li>".ltrim($banner_id[$x], '@')."</li>\n";` ?